# Url.Action can't find controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have an Html helper that defines a textbox used to feed a jquery-ui autocomplete.

```
@Html.TextBox("txtSearchArg")
```

The javascript is in the /Scripts folder.

```
    $("#txtSearchArg").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var clinician = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@(Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Home"))'
            data: { "term": request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("in success");
                response(clinician);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I am using @Url.Action method 
In my HomeController, I have an Autocomplete method.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public JsonResult Autocomplete(string term)
    {
        ... JSON gets created here
        return Json(result3, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I pass a url parameter to my $.ajax method like the code above, the response is 404, not found.  In debug, the dynamic js shows as "url: '/Home/Autocomplete'".  But when I pass it like so (copied form the dynamic js):

```
url: '/Home/Autocomplete'
```

It finds the HomeController Autocomplete method just fine.

How can I use the Url.Action method so that it finds the HomeController and the Autocomplete method?

Comment: Did you add [httpPost]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use razor syntax in a javascript file.  You will need to move your code to the view so that it is rendered properly.

A possible solution could be something like this:

in your view (e.g. .cshtml file):

```
<script>
    var autoCompleteUrl = '@(Url.Action("Autocomplete", "Home"))';
</script>
```

Then in your js just replace:

```
 $("#txtSearchArg").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        var clinician = new Array();
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: autoCompleteUrl
            data: { "term": request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("in success");
                response(clinician);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```